# jQuery .data issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I am using jQuery .data() to add some var's to an element. That part is working fine as you can see below:

```
$('#r' + id).data("ruleData", {
                ruleName: name,
                ruleID: id,
                ruleDesc: desc,
                ruleCat: cat,
                functionName: functionName
            });
```

The issue is, the function that this is in can be run more than once if the user goes back to a specific step. If they changes the information on that step it is just adding to this data object.

Is there a way I can clear all the contents of the object right before it creates it each time so its always up to date content?

Couldn't think of a way to do it since it's dynamically applying it to multiple elements.

Comment: "All contents"? Generated HTML content, or "ruleData" content?  Or both?

Comment: Did you try `removeData('ruleData')`

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue.  The new object should replace the old.  What version of jquery are you using?

Comment: PaulProgrammer - Just the ruleData

Aurn - $.removeData('ruleData'); didnt work

Comment: Unable to reproduce http://jsfiddle.net/z4WDr/

Comment: jQuery 1.9.1 is the version

Comment: looks like this is my mistake. There happened to be another element on the page with the same id that i didnt account for and it caused it to act weird. It overwrites each time as intended. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

run this first, and then the code you have above. It'll clear the data.

```
$('#r' + id).data("ruleData", {
            ruleName: '',
            ruleID: '',
            ruleDesc: '',
            ruleCat: '',
            functionName: ''
        });
```